# How to pronounce the slash sign

Tags: reading-aloud

> There is another common business type of partnership 51% / 49%.

Would it be correct to say “to” instead of the slash sign while speaking, like:

> 51% **to** 49%

If “to” is wrong, please correct me.

Answer (score 36):

Symbols should always be pronounced to denote their intended *meaning*. For example, the ampersand symbol (`&`) *means* "and", and so is pronounced that way:

> eg "Smith & Jones" would be read as "Smith and Jones".

You would not expect someone to pronounce the symbol as "ampersand" when encountering it in a text.

The "slash" symbols (`/` and `\`) are *described* by the terms "forward slash" and "backslash" but as mathematical symbols they can denote a number of things. Therefore the reader needs to understand their intended meaning before they can be read properly.

In your example...

> There is another common business type of partnership 51% / 49%.

... it seems to me that this is representing a *ratio*.

A ratio expressed using the format "51:49" would normally be pronounced:

> Fifty-one to forty-nine.

However, when it comes to percentages it is quite common to omit the ratio altogether. You may be familiar with the expression "50/50" (fifty-fifty) meaning an equal split two-ways. It may, therefore, be acceptable to say:

> Fifty-one forty-nine.

There are other uses for the slash symbol, for example, a *fraction*. Although fractions are traditionally displayed vertically with the numerator above the denominator, it is also common for some to display these on one line using a slash due to the limitations of a computer keyboard. Whatever the symbol, you should consider what it means in context before attempting to pronounce it.

Comment: Actually, the name of "/" is simply "slash", but because so many people confuse it with the backslash "\" it has become increasingly common to call "/" "forward slash".

Comment: I'm upvoting mostly for the last part, which is how I'd say it: _Fifty-one forty-nine_. Also, as a footnote, when writing the OP's sentence, I'd be more inclined to use a hyphen, not a slash: _There is another common business type of partnership 51% - 49%._ (Incidentally, this reminds me: Many sporting venues have [50-50 raffles](https://www.fundraiserhelp.com/50-50-raffle.htm). However, Las Vegas recently got an NHL expansion team, the Vegas Golden Knights. I had a chance to attend a game, and was amused to see they were conducting a 51-49 raffle. You see, the house **always** wins in Vegas.)

Comment: +1 also because of needing to be aware of the intended meaning.  So while I think saying "the odds are 50/50" as "fifty fifty" is fine and the most likely way to hear it you would not be correct to say "they have already used up 2/3 of the time" as "two three".  This has a different meaing to 50/50 and should be said as "two thirds" (or "two out of three" if the sentence was phrased a little differently).

Comment: @MontyHarder Yes, that's likely why backslash is a compound word and forward slash is not. It is important to recognise the difference though - although this is not an English language matter, in mathematics they are used to denote a rounded division and a division with a remainder. Again this comes down to knowing what you are reading.

Comment: @J.R. A dash would seem better to me than a hyphen.

Comment: @JiK - Most articles I've seen (such as [this one](https://www.dailykos.com/stories/2018/10/4/1801458/-What-if-there-is-a-50-50-split-in-the-Senate)) use hyphens, not dashes.

Comment: A hyphen or dash is also used to express a range of values.  So using it for a ratio as well is ambiguous and can be confusing.  (And a slash is also used for fractions, of course.  A colon would seem to be clearest.)

Comment: @gidds we're getting into maths here more than English. It isn't the correct way to express a ratio, but when you compare two percentages that represent a split it is essentially the same as a ratio, and the normal way to separate the two is with a slash. It would be strange to present two percentages as a ratio when percentages are, by nature, out of 100, whereas ratios are normally shown in the lowest possible terms. 50/50 is the same as 1:1.

Comment: @gidds - When I scanned through the news hits on Google for [50 50 partnership](https://www.google.com/search?q="50+50+partnership"&source=lnms&tbm=nws), I saw plenty of slashes and hyphens, but only two colons in the first 15 pages of hits.

Comment: @Astralbee Actually, it could *still* be interpreted as a compound word. I've heard that ice cream is. I'm not sure what the rule is (or if there is a rule). English is *weird!*

Answer (score 13):

Many times, slashes and hyphens are left silent when reading expressions that use them. For example:

> - Marriage is a 50/50 relationship.
> - We need to be vigilant 24/7.
> - The school will hold its first 50-50 raffle on Friday.
> - The measure passed 51-49.
> - Liverpool and Manchester played to a 2-2 tie.
> - The Supreme Court issued a 7-2 ruling yesterday.

All of those can be said aloud without the use of a preposition, and without the mention of a punctuation mark between the two numerical values. (The word *to* could be used in those last three, but it's also commonly omitted.)

I'd be inclined to read your sentence without any mention of the slash.

Comment: I'd be inclined to reword the sentence into an idiomatic form, so that it's clear that it's a comparison of percentages, and not something else. E.g. the number *5,149*, or a legal/technical reference. (Compare to *501(c)3*.) 

"There is another common business type of partnership with a 51% / 49% split," would communicate far more easily.

Answer (score 2):

It is basically representation of ratio. So there are various ways you can *say/express* it.

> It is same as to ask whether a bar chart or line graph is correct to
>   summarize a data. While both of these are appropriate/correct for the
>   task, it is completely an individual choice.

***"Obviously, something totally vague is not going to work"***

But anything that expresses correctly the proportion of how **one** is related to the **other** is CORRECT.

Answer (score 0):

Many people say it differently, and I guess all are fine. For example:

- 51% *to* 49%
- 51% *slash* 49%
- 51% *over* 49%
- 51% *or* 49%

Mathematically speaking, **over** is correct.

Comment: Perhaps _over_ would work fine for a mathematical fraction, but, in the OP's context, I'm not sure I'd classify it as a fraction. When people say things like, "We have a 50/50 partnership," it seems more like a stock phrase than a mathematical expression.

Comment: "To", "over" and "or" are not at all valid in the same contexts. They have different meanings! Even in mathematics, there is room for ambiguity: you have to agree with the author on which notation is in use, because it's not always the same. For example `x` is often used to represent a cross-product, rather than multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

The most correct answer would probably be `versus` (  or `vs` for short) but this is a little clumsy in spoken language, so most commonly the slash would become completely silent.

In this context, `to` is wrong - it would mean that you were talking about a range FROM 51% to 49%  when in fact the second number is redundant in this use.

Comment: I disagree about "to" meaning a range.  A sports call of "They won 51 to 49" doesn't mean "from" at all,  it just implies the two different scores.  Likewise you could have "X was the majority owner 51% to 49%"